flutter chrome app forwarding to chrome instead of chromium
I am able to get flutter running in Chromebook and VS code inside the Linux VM (Penguin). Additionally, I had to install chromium inside the VM in order to compile the code and view it in a browser.
$ mkdir projects
$ cd projects/

$ git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git

$ cd flutter/bin/

$ ./flutter 
Building flutter tool...
Resolving dependencies... (6.7s)
Downloading packages... (36.5s)
Got dependencies.

Use `vim ~/.bashrc`
export PATH="$PATH:/home/user/projects/flutter/bin"
export CHROME_EXECUTABLE="/usr/bin/chromium"

Rather to install chromium in the VM it there a way to forward the web app to chrome instead?
